# Firefox mobile ignores viewport

Tags: firefox, mobile, viewport

I'm testing viewport settings with different browsers on mobile phones and my tablet (Android 4). Firefox seems to be the only one that ignores my settings on the tablet. My doctype is HTML5. I couldn't find a working solution. Is there a way to deal with or a known problem?

Comment: Solved 2012-05-06: I found out, that Firefox Mobile ignores viewport settings in combination with another meta for older browsers: <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true" /> If you leave this out, everything works fine.